# Remove gray from RGB

Tags: python

Problem is that I need to remove "gray" from a set of 3 numbers.
Given values for red, green, and blue, remove the gray part.

Gray in this terminology = 50

It has to -50 from anything >=50, and can not subtract 50 from >= 255.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

I wrote the code out, and tried changing it different ways but I can't seem to get the code to remove 50 from each subset. The code runs... but it doesn't subtract the 50.

## The below are a few different changes I tried making to print out the correct numbers.

```python
color_1 = int(input())
color_2 = int(input())
color_3 = int(input())
gray = 50

if color_1 < 51:
  if color_1 > 255:
    color_1 == (color_1 - gray)

if color_2 < 51:
  color_2 - 50
    
if color_3 < 51:
  color_3 - 50

print(color_1, color_2, color_3)
```

What I input =
130
50
130
The current output is =
130
50
130
Expected output is =
80
0
80

Comment: It seems that the inequalities don't quite match what your trying to do.  For each color, `c`,  modifying the `if` part of your if statements to  `if (c >= 50) and (c < 255):`  should fix this.

Comment: @ChrisH. That definitely did help, I swear I tried using '()' and it didn't make a difference. It mostly works now, but it's still throwing error's for different inputs. However I think that's an instructor mistake, not mine.

Comment: You need to use a singular equals sign to assign a new value to a variable. So change `color_1 == (color_1 - gray)` to `color_1 = color_1 - gray`, and similarly for color _2 and _3.

Just having a line with `x - 50` is a valid Python expression, but it does not change the value of `x`. (Though, with black magic the - operator can be overloaded, but that's very much not recommended.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
color_1 = int(input())
color_2 = int(input())
color_3 = int(input())
gray = 50

if color_1 >= 50 and not color_1 >= 255:
    color_1 = color_1 - gray

if color_2 >= 50 and not color_2 >= 255:
    color_2 = color_2 - gray

if color_3 >= 50 and not color_3 >= 255:
    color_3 = color_3 - gray

print(color_1, color_2, color_3)
```

Gives you for `130 50 130` your desired output:

> 80 0 80

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!
That code works for the most part. Do you know why it worked when you used
'color_1 = color_1 - gray', and it did not when I did it? because you used the "and not" in your statement?

Comment: Sure, please mark as answer if it helped. Regarding your question - your code was wrong mainly in two aspects: 1. You had both: `if color_1 < 51` and `if color_1 > 255`. That means it's only valid for a number that is both below 51 and greater than 255. Such a number does not exist. 2. You had: `color_1 == (color_1 - gray)` "==" is a comparison operator (resulting in False) while you wanted "=" as the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

@skymon & @ChrisH provided some helpful insight to the above, when it runs against multiple numbers, it only works some of the time.

So apparently when the number is 255, it needs to print 0. When it is 50 it needs to print 0, and when it is 255 it needs to print 0. So I have made an edit to what @skymon posted. It works for the majority, however some outputs are still wrong.

```
if color_1 == 255:
    color_1 = 0
    if color_1 == 50:
        color_1 = 0
            if (color_1 >= 51) and  not (color_1 >= 255):
            color_1 = color_2 - gray
```

Changing the 'and not' function produces the same results unfortunately.

Input
10
50
90
Your output
10 50 90
Expected output
0 40 80

AND

130
50
130
Your output
130 50 130
Expected output
80 0 80

I don't know how 50 is supposed to = both 0 AND 40. The expected results make no sense.

Comment: Since your questions seems to be obviously a homework assignment, I suggest you re-read the whole assignment. Especially the part in the end where it says: "Find the smallest value, and then subtract it from all three values, thus removing the gray".

Comment: @skymon yes it is a homework assignment, which is why I asked why it did not work. I am trying my hardest to learn, not just get the right answer. I posted in here trying to learn. I apologize if it came across that I was just looking for an answer. 
 "Find the smallest value, and then subtract it from all three values, thus removing the gray" is not what the assignment is looking for. I do appreciate all the input and assistance. I was able to re-write  my code to get the correct output for 4/5 of the inputs. The 5th input appears impossible, so I'm awaiting my instructors reply now.

Answer (score 1):

```py
red_amount = int(input())
green_amount = int(input())
blue_amount = int(input())

min_value = red_amount

if green_amount < min_value:
    min_value = green_amount

if blue_amount < min_value:
    min_value = blue_amount

red_amount = red_amount - min_value
green_amount = green_amount - min_value
blue_amount = blue_amount - min_value

print(red_amount, green_amount, blue_amount)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
color_1 = int(input())
color_2 = int(input())
color_3 = int(input())

if color_1 < color_2:
  if color_1 < color_3:
    color_2 = color_2 - color_1
    color_3 = color_3 - color_1
    color_1 = (color_1 - color_1)

if color_2 < color_1:
  if color_2 < color_3:
    color_1 = color_1 - color_2
    color_3 = color_3 - color_2
    color_2 = (color_2 - color_2)

if color_3 < color_2:
  if color_3 < color_1:
    color_2 = color_2 - color_3
    color_1 = color_1 - color_3
    color_3 = (color_3 - color_3)

if color_1 == color_2:
   color_1 = color_1 - color_1
   color_2 = color_2 - color_2
   color_3 = color_3 - color_3

print(color_1, color_2, color_3)
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

The question above is from a ZyBooks lab exercise. While the answers before me address the initial input and give some correct outputs in some cases, they are not the best answer for all the inputs that the lab generates.

All inputs include:

130 50 130 / 255 255 255 / 0 0 0 / 9 0 15 / 10 50 90

The needed logic is to find the smallest number and then subtract the smallest number from all numbers.
The following code achieves that and provides the expected output for all inputs:

```
r = int(input())
g = int(input())
b = int(input())
smallest_num = 0

if (r < g) and (r < b):     
    smallest_num = r
elif (g < r) and (g < b):       #This condiditional finds the smallest number
    smallest_num = g            #out of the 3 inputs
else:
    smallest_num = b

no_grey_r = r - smallest_num    #New variables without the 'grey' value,
no_grey_g = g - smallest_num    #which is the 'equal part' i.e.
no_grey_b = b - smallest_num    #the smallest number in each color

print(f'{no_grey_r} {no_grey_g} {no_grey_b}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a  = scnr.nextInt();
      int b = scnr.nextInt();
      int c = scnr.nextInt();
      int gray = (a<b)?((a<c)?a:c):((b<c)?b:c);
      
      System.out.print(a-gray);
      System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.print(b-gray);
      System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.println(c-gray);  
   }
}
```

Comment: It's preferable not to give an answer with just code. Try to include an explanation about what problem the asker made and how your code fixes it

Answer (score 0):

```
red = int(input())
green = int(input())
blue = int(input())
grey = 0


if (red <= green) and ( red <= blue):
    grey = red
    
if (green <= red) and ( green <= blue):
    grey = green
    
if (blue <= green) and ( blue <= red):
    grey = blue
    
red = red - grey
green = green - grey
blue = blue - grey
    
print(red, green, blue)
```

Comment: Kindly consider adding English explanations of your code, highlighting relevant parts, so your answer will be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is my solution to this problem. I have seen this problem twice come up in my studies. So I figured I would help

```
color_1 = int(input())
color_2 = int(input())
color_3 = int(input())
gray = 50
mini = 0

mini= (min(color_1, color_2, color_3))

color_1 = color_1 - mini
color_2 = color_2 - mini
color_3 = color_3 - mini

print(color_1, color_2, color_3)
```

Comment: You don't need to declare gray. I forgot to take that out. Sorry

Comment: Please edit your answer if you need to change it.